# Change excel form checkbox name

Tags: forms, excel, checkbox

I am using Excel 2010. I would like to chagne the name of an excel form checkbox I've added. How can I do that, not in VBA?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can change it in the Name Box:

[image]

Comment: Wow... talk about hiding in plain sight! :)

Comment: grrr ... what have they suddenly got against a nice everything-in-one-place properties pane? Even "Format Control" didn't have any real formatting options in it...

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by editing the name box to the left of the formula bar, here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open excel sheet where to change the name of required checkbox,
2. Go to developer menu & open it,
3. Go to design mode icon & click it,
4. Select the required checkbox to change the name,
5. Right click,
6. Go to properties line & click it,
7. Go to caption line,
8. Edit the next box - this is where you can do the modification.

Comment: hope this will assisst

Answer (score 0):

To change the name of a selected object, use the Name Box above and to the left of cell A1.

If by chance you are trying to only change the capitalization of some characters, however, Excel doesn't accept this as a change, and it will revert to the original once you hit Enter.

For example - if it's called CheckBox5 and you want to change it to checkBox5, you have to rename it to something different first, then to checkBox5.